# access Properties file located in app folder in src file in android

Tags: android, properties-file

I want to access a property file from a module root, but failed to find any suitable example to access the property file as many only tells how to access from asset in android. My app structure is as follows,

```
├── app
│   ├── key.properties  <--It is my property file, which contains app keys,to be used in app 
│   └── src             <-- Here i want to access the key.properties to access some keys 
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── local.properties
```

Comment: Why don't you just put it in `/assets` or `/res/raw`?

Comment: @MikeM., because i am using git to store it on cloud and i don't want to share the keys....in this way key.properties will not be uploaded to git.

Comment: Well, I don't know thing one about git, but isn't that what the gitignore file is for?

Comment: @MikeM., well yes may be it is, but u can't use the gitignore file in gralde, where it can be used

Answer (score 3):

*Mike M* is correct in that you should use gitignore to hide your file from git so it won't be pushed on your repository.

To expand a bit on this, here's a solution to have gradle load your properties during the build, and make them available to your app via BuildConfig.

**1/ app/build.gradle**

Before the `android { ... }` plugin, add:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
try {
    props.load(file('keys.properties').newDataInputStream())
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new GradleException("Missing keys.properties file.");
}
```

**2/ app/build.gradle**

In your `buildTypes` config, add

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "KEY_MY_PROP", "\"${props.getProperty("myPropKey")}\""
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "KEY_MY_PROP", "\"${props.getProperty("myPropKey")}\""
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**3/ Any class in your app**

Your key is accessible as `BuildConfig.KEY_MY_PROP`

Comment: Thanku, your code is nice and definitile work but is there not a way to directly access the .properties file in java file as there are lot of keys in that

Comment: Sure this solution is not suitable for too many properties. Then I guess your last chance is to put the properties file in `res/raw/` or `res/assets/` as Mike M suggested. There are some details on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes . Alternatively you can use an xml file in `res/xml` instead. You'd still need to hide the file with gitignore though.