# Proper way to save and use New Relic API Key

Tags: android, newrelic, api-key

According to New Relic [docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/install-configure/install-android-apps-gradle-android-studio), I have to save it's API key on a file called `newrelic.properties` and use it onCreate of the main class. How do I avoid storing this key twice (newrelic.properties and Constants file)? How do I get the api stored in newrelic.properties file?

Places where New Relic API KEY are used:

MainActivity onCreate:

```
NewRelic.withApplicationToken("GENERATED_TOKEN").start(this.getApplication());
```

File newrelic.properties in projectname/app path

```
com.newrelic.application_token=GENERATED_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a utility class AssetsPropertyReader:

```
public class AssetsPropertyReader {
   private Context context;
   private Properties properties;

   public AssetsPropertyReader(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
          /**
           * Constructs a new Properties object.
           */
          properties = new Properties();
   }

   public Properties getProperties(String FileName) {

          try {
                 /**
                  * getAssets() Return an AssetManager instance for your
                  * application's package. AssetManager Provides access to an
                  * application's raw asset files;
                  */
                 AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
                 /**
                  * Open an asset using ACCESS_STREAMING mode. This
                  */
                 InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(FileName);
                 /**
                  * Loads properties from the specified InputStream,
                  */
                 properties.load(inputStream);

          } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 Log.e("AssetsPropertyReader",e.toString());
          }
          return properties;

   }

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
AssetsPropertyReader assetsPropertyReader = new AssetsPropertyReader(context);
Properties p = assetsPropertyReader.getProperties("MyStringsFile.properties"); //here 'MyStringsFile.properties' is the name of the file


Toast.makeText(context, p.getProperty("MyBlog"), 1).show(); //'MyBlog' is the key we want value for
```

Taken from here: http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/properties-file-in-android.html

Comment: this file is not located in /assets folder, but in projectname/app path, so it will not find it with just this code above, but i will try something similar

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is based on these topics:
[access Properties file located in app folder in src file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081348/access-properties-file-located-in-app-folder-in-src-file-in-android)

[Android - How To Get Flavor's ApplicationId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813776/android-how-to-get-flavors-applicationid?answertab=active#tab-top)

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/multiple-flavors/12374/15

**1/ app/build.gradle**

Before the android { ... } plugin, add:

```
// Check if new relic file exists
Properties props = new Properties()
try {
  props.load(file('newrelic.properties').newDataInputStream())
} catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new GradleException("Missing newrelic.properties file on /app path.")
}
```

**2/ app/build.gradle**

```
 productFlavors {
    production {
      dimension = "datatype"
      buildConfigField "String", "NEW_RELIC_API_KEY", "\"${props.getProperty("com.newrelic.application_token")}\""
    }
}
```

**3/Any class in your app. In my case is MainActivity**

```
if(isProductionFlavor()) {
    NewRelic
     .withApplicationToken(BuildConfig.NEW_RELIC_API_KEY)
     .start(this.getApplication())
}
```